# Wifi still extremely slow on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

I know there are many posts out there trying to troubleshoot the issue, but so far nothing has worked for me.

Changing the `wifi.powersave` to `2` did increase a little the network speed (from 300KB/s to 3MB/s) but that is it.

Also, I would like to understand what causes the issue, and not just randomly apply a solution found.

Here is a chunk of the log `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`

```
mai 24 20:55:02 helios systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2049] NetworkManager (version 1.36.6) is starting... (after a restart)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2049] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, no-mac-addr-change.conf) (ru>
mai 24 20:55:02 helios systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2062] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2257] manager[0x55aa05208020]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2257] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2724] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2724] hostname: static hostname changed from (none) to "helios"
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2726] dns-mgr[0x55aa051e49a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=unmanaged (auto), plugin=systemd-resolved
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2730] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.3/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver iwlwifi)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2731] manager[0x55aa05208020]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2732] manager[0x55aa05208020]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2740] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-bluetooth.so)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2741] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wwan.so)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2742] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2745] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-team.so)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2746] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.so)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2747] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2747] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2748] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2751] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.36.6/libnm-settings-plugin-ifupdown.so")
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2751] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2751] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2751] ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2830] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2830] device (lo): carrier: link connected
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2831] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2835] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): carrier: link connected
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2837] manager: (br-a00817b3f7eb): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2843] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2846] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2850] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): Activation: starting connection 'br-a00817b3f7eb' (a716798d-5710-4f19-bdf4-4babecfea96d)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2854] manager: (br-afe3bad5f59f): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2860] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2863] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2866] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): Activation: starting connection 'br-afe3bad5f59f' (44b8adf7-1ca5-4718-b8ac-8c00184a38d0)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2869] manager: (br-c37c862479f1): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2874] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2877] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2881] device (br-c37c862479f1): Activation: starting connection 'br-c37c862479f1' (9ea4c649-1e6d-4aae-b3b8-e6d3e0d3a412)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2884] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2889] device (docker0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2892] device (docker0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2895] device (docker0): Activation: starting connection 'docker0' (a62a0feb-2d24-4e56-b918-380969c5b3f8)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2897] device (veth090a135): carrier: link connected
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2899] manager: (veth090a135): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/6)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2903] device (vethfcd8943): carrier: link connected
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2905] manager: (vethfcd8943): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/7)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2908] device (wlp0s20f3): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2911] manager: (wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/8)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.2913] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.4973] failed to open /run/network/ifstate
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5120] modem-manager: ModemManager available
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5126] agent-manager: agent[68378bbbb2530c8e,:1.99/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5127] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5129] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5131] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5132] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5133] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5134] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5135] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5136] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5137] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5140] device (docker0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5141] device (docker0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5143] device (docker0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5144] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5147] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5150] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5152] device (docker0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5192] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5193] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5201] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5203] device (br-a00817b3f7eb): Activation: successful, device activated.
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5206] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5207] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5208] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5210] device (br-afe3bad5f59f): Activation: successful, device activated.
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5212] device (br-c37c862479f1): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5215] device (br-c37c862479f1): Activation: successful, device activated.
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5217] device (docker0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5218] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5220] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5388] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5388] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp0s20f3 created
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5390] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/9)
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5391] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5393] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:02 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986902.5396] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0116] policy: auto-activating connection 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' (f7b479df-aec5-421a-8dc7-2ec3769427b8)
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0122] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' (f7b479df-aec5-421a-8dc7-2ec3769427b8)
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0122] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0124] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0125] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0127] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' has security, but secrets are required.
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0127] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0128] sup-iface[079a01c3c85bd6e0,1,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0134] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0136] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0137] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0137] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz'
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0138] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0138] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0138] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0138] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0326] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0327] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0920] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.0920] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1556] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1557] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz"
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1557] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1557] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1561] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1734] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed new lease, address=192.168.0.197
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1750] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1761] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1762] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1764] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1798] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1799] policy: set 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1802] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: successful, device activated.
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1805] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
mai 24 20:55:06 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986906.1808] manager: startup complete
mai 24 20:55:07 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986907.8166] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mai 24 20:55:07 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986907.8170] policy: set 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' (wlp0s20f3) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
mai 24 20:55:07 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684986907.8196] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): state changed new lease, address=2604:3d08:4f80:700::d66b
mai 24 21:55:29 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684990529.2407] agent-manager: agent[026f7851b8f543bf,:1.99/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
mai 24 22:40:18 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993218.8868] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
mai 24 22:40:18 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993218.8868] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:40:18 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993218.8871] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
mai 24 22:40:18 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993218.8872] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0400] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0400] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0672] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0673] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mai 24 22:40:18 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993218.8871] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
mai 24 22:40:18 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993218.8872] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0400] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0400] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0672] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0673] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0673] dhcp4 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0674] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): canceled DHCP transaction
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0674] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0674] dhcp6 (wlp0s20f3): state changed no lease
mai 24 22:40:19 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993219.0881] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.5710] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.5711] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.7706] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.7713] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.8320] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.8321] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.8325] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp0s20f3 created
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.8327] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/10)
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.8329] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.8333] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:36 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993956.8337] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2388] policy: auto-activating connection 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' (f7b479df-aec5-421a-8dc7-2ec3769427b8)
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2396] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: starting connection 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' (f7b479df-aec5-421a-8dc7-2ec3769427b8)
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2396] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2400] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2403] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2409] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) access point 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' has security, but secrets are required.
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2409] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2412] sup-iface[1bacdaa12a7d6836,2,wlp0s20f3]: wps: type pbc start...
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2436] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2441] device (wlp0s20f3): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2445] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) connection 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2446] Config: added 'ssid' value 'SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz'
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2446] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2446] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2446] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256 FT-PSK SAE FT-SAE'
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2446] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2681] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.2681] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.3195] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.3196] device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.4137] device (wlp0s20f3): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
mai 24 22:52:40 helios NetworkManager[37321]: <info>  [1684993960.4138] device (wlp0s20f3): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network "SHAW-42B2-2.4GHz"
```

I don’t seem to find any relevant information here, so maybe the issue comes from the firmware? But then I don’t know which one to uninstall and so on…

Answer (score 0):

Ewww! LogVomit!

By the following the log, it seems that an IPv4 DHCP connection is set up successfully ("`manager: startup complete`". Then, at `[1684986907.8166]` (Time since boot  seconds.nanoseconds), `dhcp6` tries to set up an IPv6 connection, fails, and leaves the interface waiting for a DHCP6 response.

If you're not intentionally using IPv6, you should disable IPv6.

System settings -> Network -> click on the device

If you are intentionally using IPv6, you have a problem with your DHCP server.

Comment: Leaving the interface waiting for a DHCP6 response causes a limit on network speed?